# Using SwiftUI to bring the user from the Sign In screen to another screen?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to bring the user from the SignIn screen to another screen.
This is what I have so far:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager

    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        if userManager.user == nil {
          SignInView()
        } else {
          MainView().transition(.slide)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The idea is that initially `userManager.user` will be `nil` and so I will show the `SignInView`. When the user signs in, the `user` property is updated and since it is `@Published`, the `body` of `ContentView` should slide in the MainView.

Is this the correct approach? I also don't see the MainView sliding in. Instead, it just appears on screen.

Thanks!

---

*[Update]*

This is MainView

```
struct MainView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager

    var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        if self.userManager.user != nil {
          List(...) { 
            ...
      }
    } else {
      Text("No User")
    }

  }
}
```

}

Comment: MainView() is what type of object?

Comment: I just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a sample project. You will find the transition need an animation block to make it work the ideal way.

```
class UserManager: ObservableObject{
@Published var user : String?
}

struct ContentView: View {

 @EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager

var body: some View {
    VStack{

     if userManager.user == nil {
        SignInView(user: $userManager.user).animation(nil)
        }
     else{
        MainView().environmentObject(userManager).animation(Animation.spring().speed(1.0)).transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        }
  }
}
}

struct SignInView: View {
@Binding var user: String?

var body: some View {
    Button("adding a user", action: {
        self.user = " test"
    }
    )
}
}

struct MainView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager

var body: some View {
  VStack {
    if self.userManager.user != nil {
        List(0..<10) {
            Text(self.userManager.user! + "\($0)")
      }
} else {
  Text("No User")
}
 }
  }}
```